# How does the Java class ArrayList return an Iterator Object?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I know that you get it by calling the iterator() method on the ArrayList that you created, but what does that method look like?

Since Iterator is only an interface defined in Java, I am not sure how the ArrayList passes back a concrete implementation of the Iterator?

I know how to implement these myself for my own classes...I want to know how Java's ArrayList does it...maybe there is a concrete Iterator Class in the standard Library I don't know about?

Comment: If you have the JDK, you have a file src.zip which contains the source for ArrayList.java

Comment: `class MyCustomIterator implements Iterator` .. I recommend using grepcode, e.g. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/ArrayList.java/

Comment: I'm not that good with java...could you just confirm that somewhere in that iterator() method it creates an Iterator object which implements all of the required Iterator methods?

Comment: The exact code is: http://pastebin.com/4CApia37

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find it out youself

```
System.out.println(new ArrayList().iterator().getClass());
```

I get `class java.util.ArrayList$Itr` probably you too. `$` sign mean inner class (static or not).  And if we go inside source we'll see

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Itr();
}
```

And later in this file

```
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> { ... }
```

Comment: Why to bother yourself with getting class name (which would be meaningless in case of anonymous class, by the way), if you anyway will look at the sources. The first thing to do is just go observe sources.

Comment: ArrayList has internal implementation for Iterator as private nested class. see this source code

Answer (score 1):

The `ArrayList` class internally has an implementation of `Iterator`. Either that, or it has an internal method where it constructs an `Iterator` implementation from another class. The reason I don't know for sure is because the only way to know is to look through the source code, which I haven't done. The point of having an interface is that you don't *need* to know the internal implementation. You just know what the `Iterator` interface is capable of doing - which is defined by the interface spec.

And yes, *somewhere* there is a concrete implementation of the `Iterator` interface. The `ArrayList` class is using the constructor from such an implementation, creating the object, and returning it to you.

Answer (score 0):

The iterator looks like this

```
Iterator<T> iterator() {
  return new Iterator<T>(this);
}
```

It return a new iterator every time. 

**Note you should do something like this in you code to not end up in an endless for loop**

```
Iterator iterator = myCollections.iterator();
```

Use this iterator object to loop over you collection. 
If you do

```
while(myCollections.iterator().hasNext) {
   System.out.println(myCollections.iterator().next());
}
```

It will be an endless loop just printing the first object always.

---

## EDIT:

To answer your question it comes from [AbstractList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#iterator()) which has an concrete implementation for it.

Comment: but where does it get the implementation of Iterator to return?

Comment: It is probably an internal private class. In fact, this kind of strategy is used to decouple the concrete class from whatever class is using it. You just need to know about the Iterator interface. The same thing can happen to other Design Patterns.

Comment: ArrayList have its own `Itr`

Comment: Apologies - accidentally clicked the down vote (and didn't notice for a while)

Comment: No problem :) ... just trying to understand if anything was incorrect in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList has internally implemented the iterator as a nested class.

```
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
    int cursor;       // index of next element to return
    int lastRet = -1; // index of last element returned; -1 if no such
    int expectedModCount = modCount;

    public boolean hasNext() {
       return cursor != size;
   }
```

and then it return object of it by the method iterator()

```
 public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Itr();
 }
```

you can refer the sources code for better understanding 
[ArrayList Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.Itr)

hope this ll help