# How to check the type of an object without using instance of or getClass()

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Example situation: 
I have a television abstract superclass. Two subclasses inherit from it. Both of these two subclasses have factory methods to create their own remotes. Remote is a superclass and it has two subclasses. The remotes are able to change their respective Television's channel(in this case, a samsung remote should work with any samsung TV).

The remote classes have a changeChannel method take in a television and a channel. My question is, is there a way that I can keep this hierarchy with the methods and parameters that it currently has and not have to use conditional logic for a remote to be able to only change the channel of its own brand of television. I have provided the code below.

```
import java.util.*;

public abstract class Television{
    private int channel;

    public abstract Remote makeRemote();

    public int getChannel(){
        return channel;
    }

    public void setChannel(int c){
        channel=c;  
    }
}

import java.util.*;


public class SamsungTelevision extends Television{
    private int channel;

    public Remote makeRemote(){
        return new SamsungRemote();
    }   

}

import java.util.*;


public class SonyTelevision extends Television{
    private int channel;

    public Remote makeRemote(){
        return new SonyRemote();
    }

}

import java.util.*;


public abstract class Remote{

    public abstract void changeChannel(Television t,int channel);
}

import java.util.*;


public class SamsungRemote extends Remote{

    public void changeChannel(Television t,int channel){
        t.setChannel(channel);
        System.out.println("Samsung: Channel has been switched");
    }

}

import java.util.*;


public class SonyRemote extends Remote{

    public void changeChannel(Television t,int channel){
        t.setChannel(channel);
        System.out.println("Sony: Channel has been switched");
    }
}

import java.util.*;


public class Driver{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Television t = new SamsungTelevision();
        Television t1 = new SonyTelevision();
        Remote r=t.makeRemote();
        r.changeChannel(t,35);
        System.out.println("Samsung current channel: " + t.getChannel());
        r.changeChannel(t1,37);
        System.out.println("Sony current channel: " + t1.getChannel());
    }
}
```

Comment: *and not have to use conditional logic for a remote to be able to only change the channel of its own brand of television*? No.

Comment: There are a few ways you could go about this. Are you looking for something that would cause a compile-time error if you pass a Television of a different make? How much are you allowed to mess with the existing classes?

Comment: Current code is fine. Why do you require this check?. If you want to know just className from which code is getting executed, have one method which simply logs : this.getClass().getSimpleName();

Comment: @augray That or a way to catch an error during runtime and tell the user that they are not allowed to change the channel with that remote. I can mess with the code as much as is needed.

Comment: @sunrise76 because the way it is now, any remote can change the channel  of any TV and that's not the way it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can ensure co-existing type hierarchies from a common API can can share code & that API but still only work with their own particular implementations is using [marker interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) and [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/):

```
/**
 * Different manufacturers can extend this interface
 * to ensure compile-time compatibility of their products while
 * using standard APIs that use generics for type safety. 
 */
public interface Manufacturer {

}

/**
 * This interface marks products created by Samsung.
 */
public interface Samsung extends Manufacturer {

}

/**
 * This interface marks products created by Sony.
 */
public interface Sony extends Manufacturer {

}

public abstract class Television<M extends Manufacturer>{
    private int channel;

    //this ensures that a television only makes a remote
    //by the same manufacturer
    public abstract Remote<M> makeRemote();

    public int getChannel(){
        return channel;
    }

    public void setChannel(int c){
        channel=c;  
    }
}

public class SamsungTelevision extends Television<Samsung>{
    private int channel;

    public Remote<Samsung> makeRemote(){
        return new SamsungRemote();
    }   

}


public class SonyTelevision extends Television<Sony>{
    private int channel;

    public Remote<Sony> makeRemote(){
        return new SonyRemote();
    }

}


public abstract class Remote<M extends Manufacturer>{

    //this ensures that a remote only works with a remote
    //by the same manufacturer
    public abstract void changeChannel(Television<M> t,int channel);
}


public class SamsungRemote extends Remote<Samsung>{

    public void changeChannel(Television<Samsung> t,int channel){
        t.setChannel(channel);
        System.out.println("Samsung: Channel has been switched");
    }

}


public class SonyRemote extends Remote<Sony>{

    public void changeChannel(Television<Sony> t,int channel){
        t.setChannel(channel);
        System.out.println("Sony: Channel has been switched");
    }
}

public class Driver{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Television<Samsung> t = new SamsungTelevision();
        Television<Sony> t1 = new SonyTelevision();
        Remote<Samsung> r=t.makeRemote();
        r.changeChannel(t,35);
        System.out.println("Samsung current channel: " + t.getChannel());

        //generates a compile time error because r is a samsung remote and
        //t1 is a Sony TV
        //r.changeChannel(t1,37);
        //System.out.println("Sony current channel: " + t1.getChannel());
    }
}
```

This is nice because it creates compile-time safety. People can't even accidentally write a program which will violate the constraints of manufacturer-compatibility.

And if you want to do something that can work with TVs of any make, you can still do that too:

```
public static <M extends Manufacturer> void doSomethingWithTVOfAnyMake(Television<M> tv){
        int myChannel = tv.getChannel();
        //do more stuff...
    }
```

Comment: Okay I see. So using generics and the marker interfaces, you are able to define at compile time what a class should be working with. If I try to to use a Samsung TV with a Sony remote during runtime, then I will get an error because those two types should not be working together, as defined during compile time. Is that correct?

Comment: Almost. Actually the nice thing is that you can't try to use a Samsung TV with a Sony remote, it won't even compile. Try uncommenting the line `//r.changeChannel(t1,37);` above and then compile- you should get an error.

Comment: Ah okay I see. Thank you

Comment: Compile-time safety (and more specifically "Type safety") is usually far preferred over run-time checks. If you rely on run-time checks, you have to be sure never to miss any. If you rely on the compiler you know it'll dutifully do its job ;-) . Plus with most IDEs you get instant feedback if you write code that doesn't follow compile rules. The more difficult you make it to make mistakes, the fewer you make!

Comment: @augray `r.changeChannel(t,35);` -- Wouldn't a simpler solution be not allowing televisions in the parameters? After all, the remote was built from the TV via `r = t.makeRemote()`, so it can only work with that one, e.g., `r.changeChannel(35);`

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: That would be simpler, but it doesn't meet the constraints the poster specified. He said "a samsung remote should work with **any** samsung TV". So the remote can't just keep a reference to the specific TV that created it- it needs to know about the manufacturer of the TV. You could make it so the TVs made the remotes with info about the manufacturer, and then reported their manufacturer when passed into the remote. But again, why not go for compile time safety over that solution which would require run-time checks?

Answer (score 0):

A factory method would do it for you. From the GoF reference:

[image: Factory Method pattern]

Applying it where remotes are created by TV's:

[image: Factory method applied to TV code]

You must not use a `television` argument on the `changeChannel()` method. That is really the source of why you need to do checks.

This is precisely how `Collection.iterator()` works. Furthermore, many concrete `Iterator`s are not documented in the Java API (they are inner classes of the concrete collection, see [How does the Java class ArrayList return an Iterator Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26180592/1168342)).

You could take a similar approach in your design and say that clients of remotes don't need to know what precise class they are, since they just want to use them to change channels. You could make the `SamsungRemote` a private inner class of the `SamsungTV` and the `createRemote()` method always returns an upcasted type of Remote.